# Ramban and Techelet

Tags: techeles, ramban

Any indication of how the Ramban would hold on the shita of tekhelet (ratio, knots,etc)?

I was told there is a Milchamos that alludes to it but can’t find it.

Comment: Maybe check the Milchamos which writes that the Baal Hamor exempted himself from  tzizts ,maybe it discusses it there, Shabbos 12a